# How to handle an ASP.NET MVC ActionResult Exception?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a custom ActionResult which is more deeply encountering System.Web.HttpException when the remote host closes the connection.  I've already overridden the Controller's OnException method but it's not getting caught there.  The ASP.NET MVC pipeline is already done executing my Controller's Action and is now executing the returned ActionResult when it encounters this exception.

Presently, it's bubbling up and being cluttering my log as an ERROR.  I'd rather not filter these out at logging time, because I don't consider a remote host aborting the download of the content to be an error.

I'd rather handle this error directly, but I can't tell where.  Controller.OnException doesn't work, and so I doubt the IExceptionFilter would either.  I could use Application_OnError but I fear that is too high up.

Isn't there a more MVC'ish way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no other points to catch exceptions between Controller.OnException and Application_OnError. Be Brave and use Application_OnError

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) to handle exceptions thrown in the controller action. As you pointed out in your question, I would suspect the error is beyond the scope of this attribute. That would leave only Application_OnError.

You could add a whitelist to your error handling code to ignore specific errors (specific type with specific code and maybe specific source/stacktrace).